# DSLCalendarView set current date

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I am using DSLCalendarView in my project below is the link:
https://github.com/PeteC/DSLCalendarView
I want to set current date selected at start up of calendar.
 thank you

Answer (score 0):

File->  DSLCalendarDayView.m

```
if (self.selectionState == DSLCalendarDayViewNotSelected) {
    NSUInteger flags = NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit;
    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:flags fromDate:[self.day date]];
    NSDateComponents *componentsOfToday = [calendar components:flags fromDate:[NSDate date]];
    NSDate *date = [calendar dateFromComponents:components];
    NSDate *dateToday = [calendar dateFromComponents:componentsOfToday];



    if (self.isInCurrentMonth) {

        if ([date isEqualToDate:dateToday]) {
            [[UIColor colorWithRed:(240/255.0) green:(240/255.0) blue:(239/255.0) alpha:1] setFill];
            UIRectFill(self.bounds);
            [[[UIImage imageNamed:@"DSLCalendarToday"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(20, 20, 20, 20)] drawInRect:tmpBounds];
        }
        else
        {
            [[UIColor colorWithRed:(240/255.0) green:(240/255.0) blue:(239/255.0) alpha:1] setFill];
            UIRectFill(self.bounds);
        }
    }
    else {

        if ([date isEqualToDate:dateToday]) {
            [[UIColor colorWithRed:(212/255.0) green:(212/255.0) blue:(212/255.0) alpha:1] setFill]; //even if it is not current month, current day is colored
        } else {
            [[UIColor colorWithRed:(228/255.0) green:(228/255.0) blue:(227/255.0) alpha:1] setFill];
        }
        UIRectFill(self.bounds);
    }
```

} else ...